# Not reuse data with ReusableCell of CollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have tableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTime", for: indexPath) as! TimeViewCell
        let showHour = self.infoWripper.sorted(by: { $0.hour < $1.hour })[indexPath.row]

        cell.labelTime.text = showHour.showHour()

        cell.dataForShow = showHour.showFullTime()


        return cell
    }
```

Cell of TableView contents `UICollectionView` with cells.

```
class TimeViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelTime: UILabel!

    var dataForShow = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

    }

}

extension TimeViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return dataForShow.count
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionCell

        cell.labelCollection.text = dataForShow[indexPath.row]

        //heightForCell = collectionView.contentSize.height

        return cell
    }

}

class CustomCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelCollection: UILabel!

}
```

When I open VC with table - view is OK, but when I begin scrolling - I see, that data not correct (reuse), but I can't find my mistake.
before scroll:

[image]

after:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload the collection view in your cell.
Try this:

```
class TimeViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    ....
    var dataForShow = [String]() {
        didSet {
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
```